# Expressionengine Email Contact Form Tags and Success Messages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

Does anyone know of a way to create a custom success message and post to the expression engine processing controller manually?

I'm using jQuery validator, and usually what I would do is something like this:

```
   submitHandler: function(form) {
    var data = $(form).serialize();
        $.post(
            '/system/expressionengine/templates/default_site/global.group/form.php',
            data),
        function(data){
                $('#contact-form').html('<div id="success">We’ll get back to you.</div>');

            }
        );
    }
 });
```

Unfortunately with the expression engine {exp:email:contact_form} tags it posts straight to a page and always redirects the user.

Does anyone know of a way to post or properly format the data so that handler will accept the post data and allow a seamless form submission experience?

Comment: I don't know how to do this in EE contact form, might be easy I just don't know.  It's definitely something you can do in Solspace's FreeForm.  Feature comparison: http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/freeform/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, what you have to do is post to the site url, you cannot use a custom php handler without a lot of work.  I found this out by looking where the {exp:email:contact_form} posts to.  You also have to disable CSRF protection, or find a way to snag the XID from the return data.  (I just disabled it because we're not doing anything that is data sensitive)

```
    submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/",
                type: "post",
                dataType: "html",           
                data: $('#contact_form').serialize(),
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {

                },
                success: function(html, textStatus, jqXHR) 
                {


                }

            });

        }
```